# EmberJS - Ember Simple Auth Oath2 'grant _type' not defined

Tags: ember.js

I've been following the Ember Simple Auth walkthrough available [here](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#authenticators). I have added the various code snippets as instructed but when I submit my login form I receive a 'grant_type' not defined error.

Here is the current setup:

```
// Login Form
        <form {{action 'authenticate' on='submit'}}>
          <label for="identification">Login</label> {{input value=identification placeholder='Enter Login' class='form-control'}}
          <br>
          <label for="password">Password</label> {{input value=password placeholder='Enter Password' class='form-control' type='password'}}
          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
        </form>

        {{#if errorMessage}}
          <p>
            <strong>Login failed: </strong>
            <code>{{errorMessage}}</code>
          </p>
        {{/if}}

//index.js controller

import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  actions: {
    invalidateSession() {
      this.get('session').invalidate();
    },
    authenticate() {
      let {identification, password } = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
      this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:oath2', identification, password).catch((reason) => {this.set('errorMessage', reason.error)
    })
    }
  }

});

//application route

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin);
    // authenticators/oath.js

import OAuth2PasswordGrantAuthenticator from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/oauth2-password-grant';

export default OAuth2PasswordGrantAuthenticator.extend({
  serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://server:port/api/token',


});

//api endpoint

var tokenRouter = express.Router();

tokenRouter.post('/api/token', function(req, res) {


  if (req.body.grant_type === 'password') {
    if (req.body.username === 'letme' && req.body.password === 'in') {
      res.status(200).send('{"access_token": "secret token!"}');
    } else {
      res.status(400).send('{ "error": invalid_grant_type" }')
    }
    } else {
      res.status(400).send(' { "error": "unsupported_grant_type" }')
    }

})

app.use('/', tokenRouter)
```

The request is successfully sent to my endpoint and the 500 error is generated with the message that grant_type is not defined. Looking at the request, it doesn't look like the username or password are being sent either.

As far as I can tell my code is identical to the code from the documentation and supplementary video but I am obviously missing something.

Comment: Does your index controller actually have properties named `identification` and `password`? (Did you try `console.log(identification,password)` in the middle of your `authenticate` method?) Also, who is generating the 500 error if the server endpoint you show generates only 200 and 400s? And why `import ApplicationRouteMixin ` in your route if you do not extend it?

Comment: Hi! Yes a console.log in the authenticate action prints both identification and password values to the console. I imagine the 500 error is generated because the grant_type is empty so the if statement encasing the 200/400 codes is not triggered. I know this endpoint is being triggered because of a console.log. Not extending the mixin was an input error on my part. I corrected this but it didn't affect my 500 no grant_type return. I've changed the question to reflect the change to application oute

Comment: Is `'authenticator:oath2'` also an SO input error or your actual code? "Oath" is now a company, the authentication method is "oa*u*th2". (However, from my reading of the ember-simple-auth code, a wrong name there should lead to an error before any API calls are made.)

Comment: That was a great catch. I've made that correction (and renamed the authenticator.js as it was also incorrect) and it still produces the grant_type error. On the walkthrough documentation grant_type isn't even mentioned so I assume its an internal part of the addon that is supposed to just work.

Comment: grant_type is indeed added in the respective authentication ([see the code on github](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/051a0d4f3fe623bfc1c791643831b2b373b4e835/addon/authenticators/oauth2-password-grant.js#L227)). My next idea would be to confirm that the instance of the authenticator is indeed of the correct type, but I do not know how without trying and do not have the ember app where I used ember-simple-auth around anymore, sorry.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out in the end.

After checking the Form Data in the Network tab of the Chrome debug tools it was clear that the grant_type was being sent correctly.

My issue was a missing bit of body-parser middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```